Python equivalent of HttpClient PostAsync for sending an array of parameters as part of an API get request
I have been unable to find how to use similar PostAsync for an enterprise API.
This is the example from documenation in C#:
string json = string.Empty;
 
using ( HttpClient client = new HttpClient() )
{
   string object= "UserNames";
   string method = "methodname";
   string requestUrl = $"http://server/service/object/invoke/{object}?method={method}";
 
   // provide token in the Authorization header
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(
      "Authorization",
      "b/authorizationkey" );
 
   string[] parameters = new[] { "sa", "", "", "", "" };
 
   // pass the array of parameters as the request data
   string contentStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( parameters );
   
   // send the post request
   HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync( requestUrl.ToString(), new StringContent( contentStr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json" ) ).Result;
 
   using ( HttpContent content = response.Content )
   {
      Task<string> result = content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      json = result.Result;
   }
}

I've been using 'requests' package successfully for getting information from the api but am at a roadblock when trying to find an equivalent way to PostAsync.
Also, I know this isn't a great post, but I need to start a post somewhere to start to be able to upvote or downvote things here.

You can use python's multi-threading library to call requests.post() in another thread.

This question is similar to: Python requests call with URL using parameters. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@StephenNewell Isn't this question about sending the request asynchronously, not about how to encode parameters?

@Barmar - I can't honestly tell.  The first sentence makes it sound like it's a parameter issue, and the second to last paragraph makes me think it's about being async.

Apologies for using some incorrect terminology. I can currently use requests with parameters to obtain some information via the API. To run a different type of API request, I need to pass some information via what I see in the documentation as client.PostAsync but I'm unsure how to do that in python.
